# how to write items in string on a new line

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, newline

I'm very new to python, so please bear with me while I try to explain my problem :)

Instructions given:

1. for each item in "list", write that item in a new line to the end of the file specified by "filename."
2. `list = [this, is, a, sentence]`
3. `def newlines (filename, list):`

I've found online a code that works, but it involves f.seek(0) and we haven't learned to use seek or to place a number inside the (). I was just wondering if there was another "simpler" way to write this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in l:
        f.write(item+'\n')
```

If this is the only list you want to write to the file, use `'w'` option. Else you can use the append `'a'` option to append strings to the end of the file.

Based on @Jon Clements's comment, you can replace the for loop as follows :

```py
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:
    print(*the_list, sep='\n', file=f)
```

Comment: I have assumed `list = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence']`

Comment: Instead of the loop... could also use: `print(*the_list, sep='\n', file=f)`...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you want. But let me put my answer here for you to check.

```
def newlines(l):
    f = open("newfile.txt", "w+")
    for i in l:
        f.write(i+"\n")
    f.close()

ls = ["this", "is", "a", "sentence"]
newlines(ls)
```

This creates a new file if it doesn't exist and writes the contents of the list line by line.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Like @Suraj mentioned, you can use "a" instead of "w" in case this is not the only list you want to add to the file. "a" appends the list elements to the end of the file.

Comment: No problem! And may I have a look at the traceback to help you with the error? Because @Suraj's code works perfectly fine for me with not errors.

Comment: Is your file in the same location as your code ? Also you dont have to be afraid of your professor, this is just a doubt you have :)

Comment: Make sure that your code and the text file are in the same location.

Comment: That might be the reason. Otherwise the code works just fine. Anyways, I hope you got the answer you were looking for! Don't forget to [accept the best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to your question!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer. You can try this out and change your code accordingly.

```
def newlines(filename,list):
f=open(filename+".txt","w+")
for i in list:
    f.write(i+"\n")
f.close()

ls = [this, is, a, sentence]
newlines("test",ls)
```